Robust or Stochastic Optimization Approach for Maximizing Profit with Limited Price Information
I am tackling a linear maximization problem where I need to select the optimal product among several options over a series of weeks, given certain constraints, in order to maximize future profit. The decision variables are binary, indicating whether or not a particular product is chosen.
The objective function is expressed as:
$$
\max_{j} \sum_{i} choice(j) \cdot c_{i,j}^T p_{i,j}$$
Where:
$c_{i,j}$ represents the production quantity of product $j$ in week $i$,
$p_{i,j}$ represents the price of product $j$ in week $i$,
$choice(j)$ is a binary variable indicating the selection of product $j$, and The summation is over all weeks $i$.
However, I encounter a challenge because $p_{i,j}$ is not fully known. It is a time series, and I lack future values as well as extensive historical data. To address this issue, I'm considering either Robust Optimization or Stochastic Optimization techniques. Which approach should I pursue, and how can I implement it effectively to maximize profit in this scenario?

it's not a real answer but my advice is to estimate the $p_{ij}$ and use the estimates. How you optimize ( robust, stochastic whatever ) isn't going to matter if the $p_{ij}$ are way off. So, the safest thing to do is get good estimates.  How you do that I can't say but its wasn't clear what was missing and why. ? Also, what data is available for estimation ?

The problem is i don't have much history of $p_{ij}$, only 3 years, optimization doesn't take much time only 1s, so doing 100-1000 optimization for different values of $p_{ij}$ is feasible.

Hi Anasse: It's definitely feasible but if you don't know what $p_{ij}$ are, how does an optimization help ? 3 years of data seems like a good amount to me but I'm unfamiiar with the data and what time interval etc. Basically, you need to get good estimates of $p_{ij}$.

the data i have is from 2021, price per week of each product, so say i  have 159 entries, and i want to maximize projected profit over the next year, so basically i need to make sure that the optimal chosen product isn't too sensitive to infered prices.

right. if you're interested in an approximate solution, then I think you're approach is correct. Run many scenarios with different values for $p_{ij}$ and see how the result changes depending on the chosen value of $p_{ij}$. But there must be ways to estimate the $p_{ij}$ with limited data. I don't know what they are because I don't understand what data is available.

yes, surely i can estimate future prices, it's not that hard, it's just that i want to choose the best product that is the least sensible to fluctuations in estimated prices (because of their nature), and that is why i mentioned robust optimization.

Hi Anasse: Sorry for confusion but what's the need for robust optimization. If you vary the values of $p_{ij}$ and run multiple optimizations, that will tell you if your result is sensitive to the value of $p_{ij}$.

Actually i don't want to check the sensitivity of my optimal solution, i want a solution that it's not sensible to the randomness in the prices. Hope this helps.

aaaaaaaaaaaaah. now I get it. that's interesting and I have no current experience with that type of formulation. It sounds like trying to "maximize the minimum" might be a robust approach ? It's not my area so I can't help. I'm sorry about that but hopefully my questions led to some slight clarity on the problem.

They sure did, Thanks Mr.Mark

your welcome but maybe a "minimize the maximum" type formulation might be robust ? That's all I can add. that can maybe be robust because you're minimizing a max.
